# Converting Data Type Postgres -- > Mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sqldatatypes

I would like to know what is the relevant data type for Postgress `INTEGER[]` on MSSQL ?

postgres Type  `INTEGER[]`,That is the mapping type in MSSQL. :)

Comment: Does MSSQL support arrays? INTEGER[] is just an array of integers

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes. I wanted to know MSSQL support type ?

Comment: There is no array data type in MSSQL. So, you would need to fake it by using a table or view, see, http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=168336